# Div overflowing

Tags: html, overflow

I have created a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sawaira/owkvq9bo/8/

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="navbar-text">RunAs:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="RunAs" class="form-control" value="" onchange="onchangeRunAs()" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event)" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="navbar-text">
                                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Account/SignOut">Sign out</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; background-color:#222222; height:100%; width:70px; position:fixed;">
            <br />


                        <center><a href="/Home/abc"><img src="../../Content/images/.png" title="abc" /></a></center><br /><br />
            <center><a href="/Home/adfadf"><img src="../../Content/images/time.png" title="adfa-Balance" /></a></center><r />
           />
          />

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content" id="content" style="margin-left:70px;width:1700px">
            <table cellpadding="0">
                <tr valign="bottom">
                    <td><img src="../../Content/images/cal48.png"></td>
                    <td><h2><span class="label label-primary">My Personal Dashboard</span></h2></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

<body>



   <div >
        <!-- This is the HTML element that will be used to render the KeyLines component -->

        <div id="page" class="pagestyle">
        </div>



        <div style="position:relative;height:700px; width:1500px;">
                <div id="loading" style="position:absolute;height:700px; width:1200px;">                  
                    <marquee id="loading-image" behavior="alternate" scrollamount="30">Initializing</marquee>
                </div>
                <div id="kl" style="position:relative;height:700px; width:1200px;float:left;border: 2px solid #0094ff;overflow:hidden" class="listControl" >  
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
               </div>
```

Essentially, on scrolling the blue borders overlap with the nav bar. I do not want this to happen, but not sure what is the cause.

I cannot change the height/width to be auto, as it has to meet some requirements.Otherwise the page does not display the contents properly.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better a add a jsfiddle or something like that

Comment: Please edit your original post instead of adding comments.